# Index and Match multiple columns and find answer for 3rd in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

This may just be a simple answer that I'm looking too much into.

On my first sheet I have 5 columns of data from where I want to pull information.

```
   [A1]"Pickup Date" [B1]"Truck #" [C1] "Trailer #" [D1] "Customer Name"
```

On the second sheet I have three of the same columns

```
[A1] "Pickup Date" [B1]"Truck Number" [C1]"Customer Name"
```

I'm Wondering if I have supplied the "Pickup Date" and "Truck Number" on the second sheet if I can grab the corresponding "Customer Name" from sheet 1 and paste it into C2 on sheet 2.

Here's the formula I have tried in C2 under customer name.  I know it's not in correct format but I need both the Pickup Date and Truck Number to match and paste the

```
customer name=INDEX(Table1,( MATCH(A1,Table1[Pick Up Date],0)&MATCH(B2,Table1[Truck #],0)),4)
```

Thanks For your help

Comment: What if there are many Trailers for one truck with multiple customers?  Which one should be fetched from Sheet1?

Comment: For now just the first one that comes up in the list.  I may need to use macro later on to create another row and add the second customer.  For now I just need to know the first customer from the given date and Truck #

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar issue and the solution I found was to place a CONCATENATE formula in the last column on the first sheet that combines the 'Pickup Date' and 'Truck Number' like the following: `=CONCATENATE(A2,B2)` and use CONCATENATE in the INDEX(MATCH) formula in the second sheet like the following:
`=INDEX('Sheet1'!A:E,MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,B2),'Sheet1'!E:E,0),4)`
This formula looks at columns `A:E` in the excel sheet named `Sheet1`.  If your sheet is named something else, you will have to change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this array formula to do an INDEX MATCH with multiple criteria.

```
=INDEX( Table1[Customer Name], MATCH( A1, IF(Table1[Truck #] = B2, Table1[Pick Up Date]), 0) )
```

I assume that cell A1 has your pick up date to match and B2 has your truck number to match.

Enter this and press CTRL + Enter to save it as an array formula (instead of just enter).